# When slicing a 1 row pandas dataframe the slice becomes a series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

Why when I slice a pandas dataframe containing only 1 row, the slice becomes a pandas series?
How can I keep it a dataframe?

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3]],columns=['a','b','c'])
df
Out[37]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3


a=df.iloc[0]

a
Out[39]: 
a    1
b    2
c    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: That's not a slice. Try a true slice like `df.iloc[0:1]`.

Comment: @Goyo I have to disagree, if you check the docstring for `slice`, it may be either `slice(stop)` or `slice(start, stop[, step])`, so just using a scalar is indeed a valid slice.

Comment: @BradSolomon Yes, passing a scalar to `slice` will return a instance of `slice`. Yet indexing `df.iloc` with a single scalar won't slice `df`. `df.iloc.__getitem__(slice(n))` will return a `DataFrame` or will raise an exception, it will never return a `Series`. `df.iloc[0]` is the same as `df.iloc.__getitem__(0)` --no slicing involved.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To avoid the intermediate step of re-converting back to a DataFrame, use double brackets when indexing:

```
a = df.iloc[[0]]
print(a)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

Speed:

```
%timeit df.iloc[[0]]
192 µs per loop

%timeit df.loc[0].to_frame().T
468 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can slice by index

```
a=df.iloc[df.index==0]

a
Out[1782]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_frame()` and `T` to transpose:

```
df.loc[0].to_frame()

   0
a  1
b  2
c  3
```

and

```
df.loc[0].to_frame().T

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

OR

Option #2 use double brackets `[[]]`

```
df.iloc[[0]]

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

Comment: still I have the columns as indeces