# `.loc` and `.iloc` with MultiIndex'd DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When indexing a MultiIndex-ed DataFrame, it seems like `.iloc` assumes you're referencing the "inner level" of the index while `.loc` looks at the outer level.

For example:

```
np.random.seed(123)
iterables = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=idx)

# .loc looks at the outer index:

print(df.loc['qux'])
# df.loc['two'] would throw KeyError
              0        1        2        3
second                                    
one    -1.25388 -0.63775  0.90711 -1.42868
two    -0.14007 -0.86175 -0.25562 -2.79859

# while .iloc looks at the inner index:

print(df.iloc[-1])
0   -0.14007
1   -0.86175
2   -0.25562
3   -2.79859
Name: (qux, two), dtype: float64
```

Two questions:

Firstly, why is this?  Is it a deliberate design decision?

Secondly, can I use `.iloc` to reference the outer level of the index, to yield the result below?  I'm aware I could first find the last member of the index with `get_level_values` and then `.loc`-index with that, but wandering if it can be done more directly, either with funky `.iloc` syntax or some existing function designed specifically for the case.

```
# df.iloc[-1]
qux   one     0.89071  1.75489  1.49564  1.06939
      two    -0.77271  0.79486  0.31427 -1.32627
```

Comment: the index is a linear list that is emulated into a table. you'll notice that in your second example, the index `-1` actually consists of _two_ values: `Name: (qux, two)`. It's more that `loc` allows referencing a full index (e.g. `df.loc['qux', 'two']`) or a partial one, but it is in order. you could do a `reset_index` and set the index in the other order if you wanted to.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, this is a [deliberate design decision](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15228):

> `.iloc` is a strict positional indexer, it **does not** regard the structure
>   at all, only the first actual behavior. ... `.loc` **does** take into
>   account the level behavior. [emphasis added]

So the desired result given in the question is not possible in a flexible manner with `.iloc`.  The closest workaround, used in several similar questions, is

```
print(df.loc[[df.index.get_level_values(0)[-1]]])
                    0        1        2        3
first second                                    
qux   one    -1.25388 -0.63775  0.90711 -1.42868
      two    -0.14007 -0.86175 -0.25562 -2.79859
```

Using [double brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818612/when-slicing-a-1-row-pandas-dataframe-the-slice-becomes-a-series/45818698#45818698) will retain the first index level.

Comment: I might have missed something, but I needed to add `.unique()`to make this work as I expected.
`df.loc[[df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()[-1]]]`

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```python
df.iloc[[6, 7], :]
Out[1]:
                     0         1         2         3
first second
qux   one    -1.253881 -0.637752  0.907105 -1.428681
      two    -0.140069 -0.861755 -0.255619 -2.798589
```

Where `[6, 7]` correspond to the actual row indexes of these lines, as you can see below:

```python
df.reset_index()
Out[]:
  first second         0         1         2         3
0   bar    one -1.085631  0.997345  0.282978 -1.506295
1   bar    two -0.578600  1.651437 -2.426679 -0.428913
2   baz    one  1.265936 -0.866740 -0.678886 -0.094709
3   baz    two  1.491390 -0.638902 -0.443982 -0.434351
4   foo    one  2.205930  2.186786  1.004054  0.386186
5   foo    two  0.737369  1.490732 -0.935834  1.175829
6   qux    one -1.253881 -0.637752  0.907105 -1.428681
7   qux    two -0.140069 -0.861755 -0.255619 -2.798589
```

This also works with `df.iloc[[-2, -1], :]` or `df.iloc[range(-2, 0), :]`.

---

**EDIT: Turning it into a more generic solution**

Then it is possible to get a generic function:

```python
def multindex_iloc(df, index):
    label = df.index.levels[0][index]
    return df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(label)]

multiindex_loc(df, -1)
Out[]:
                     0         1         2         3
first second
qux   one    -1.253881 -0.637752  0.907105 -1.428681
      two    -0.140069 -0.861755 -0.255619 -2.798589


multiindex_loc(df, 2)
Out[]:
                     0         1         2         3
first second
foo   one     2.205930  2.186786  1.004054  0.386186
      two     0.737369  1.490732 -0.935834  1.175829
```

Comment: Looking for a more generic method given I'll have DataFrames of different length

Comment: @BradSolomon: how generic should it be compared to `df.iloc[-1]`?

Comment: about the same ... genericalness (?) as `df.iloc[-1]` would be ideal

Comment: @BradSolomon: made a function that is more generic, is it better?

Comment: Thanks for updating, but my question specifically asks if this is possible without referencing the index levels as you do in your function.  I'm wondering if there is an indexing method built for this or syntax within `iloc` that will do this.

Comment: @BradSolomon: so I think the short answer is no. Moreover Github indicates a couple of issues with Multiindex/iloc (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20iloc%20multiindex%20), maybe it's not the way to go.

Comment: It seems this solution also sorts the indices in the ascending order (?!)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.swaplevel.html#pandas-multiindex-swaplevel) method to reorder the index before using `loc`.

```
df.swaplevel(0,-1).loc['two']
```

With the sample data from your question, it looks like this:

```
>>> df
                     0         1         2         3
first second                                        
bar   one    -1.085631  0.997345  0.282978 -1.506295
      two    -0.578600  1.651437 -2.426679 -0.428913
baz   one     1.265936 -0.866740 -0.678886 -0.094709
      two     1.491390 -0.638902 -0.443982 -0.434351
foo   one     2.205930  2.186786  1.004054  0.386186
      two     0.737369  1.490732 -0.935834  1.175829
qux   one    -1.253881 -0.637752  0.907105 -1.428681
      two    -0.140069 -0.861755 -0.255619 -2.798589

>>> df.loc['bar']
               0         1         2         3
second                                        
one    -1.085631  0.997345  0.282978 -1.506295
two    -0.578600  1.651437 -2.426679 -0.428913

>>> df.swaplevel().loc['two']
              0         1         2         3
first                                        
bar   -0.578600  1.651437 -2.426679 -0.428913
baz    1.491390 -0.638902 -0.443982 -0.434351
foo    0.737369  1.490732 -0.935834  1.175829
qux   -0.140069 -0.861755 -0.255619 -2.798589
```

`swaplevel` is a MultiIndex method, but you can call it directly on the DataFrame.
The default is to swap the inner two levels, so if you have more than two levels in the multi index, you should explicitly state the level you want to swap.

```
df.swaplevel(0,-1).loc['two']
```