# Index or slice multilevel columns by integer position

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select multilevel columns in a DataFrame. For example:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 6), index=index[:6], columns=index[:6])
```

Output:

```
first              bar                 baz                 foo          
second             one       two       one       two       one       two
first second                                                            
bar   one     1.031494 -1.115284 -0.154907  0.044911  2.443488 -0.534575
      two    -0.236643  1.547236  2.132647  0.366896 -0.710489 -0.478956
baz   one    -0.365648  1.517573  0.668234  0.408448 -0.427475 -1.205160
      two     1.362631 -0.785439  1.549837 -0.693337  0.610976 -1.989460
foo   one    -0.449393  0.195214  1.120589  0.413219 -0.820709  0.349553
      two    -1.128392 -0.590630  0.559310 -0.225504  1.721240  1.326330
```

I can now select level 0 == 'bar' like this:

```
df.loc[:,slice("bar")]
```

Which gives me:

```
first              bar          
second             one       two
first second                    
bar   one     1.031494 -1.115284
      two    -0.236643  1.547236
baz   one    -0.365648  1.517573
      two     1.362631 -0.785439
foo   one    -0.449393  0.195214
      two    -1.128392 -0.590630
```

This: `df.loc[:,slice(df.columns.levels[0][0])]` also works and gives the same result.

My question: Can i get the above output, but using the integer position of the column 'bar'. So instead of:

```
df.loc[:,slice("bar")]
```

I would like to use:

```
    df.loc[:,slice(0)]
```

and get exactly the same output, namely:

```
first              bar          
second             one       two
first second                    
bar   one     1.031494 -1.115284
      two    -0.236643  1.547236
baz   one    -0.365648  1.517573
      two     1.362631 -0.785439
foo   one    -0.449393  0.195214
      two    -1.128392 -0.590630
```

Further, if i do:

```
df.loc[:,(slice(0), slice(0))]
```

I would like to get:

```
first              bar          
second             one 
first second                    
bar   one     1.031494 
      two    -0.236643 
baz   one    -0.365648 
      two     1.362631 
foo   one    -0.449393 
      two    -1.128392
```

given that i am now saying "give me the column where level 0 == 0 (or "bar") and level 1 == 0 (or "one")". I could achieve this outcome using:

```
df.loc[:,(slice("bar"), slice("one"))]
```

but would like to use integers instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you're going to find this unsatisfying but I think it may not be possible to do directly what you want to do.

In short, [`.iloc` behaves differenlty than `.loc` for MultiIndexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967702/loc-and-iloc-with-multiindexd-dataframe).  The result is that if you want to use integers you'll need to reference the columns themselves as you're doing now.

Take this example with your DataFrame:

```
first           bar           baz           foo       
second          one    two    one    two    one    two
first second                                          
bar   one    -0.771 -0.211 -0.353  1.305 -0.595  1.174
      two    -1.777 -2.293  1.492 -2.638  0.197  0.406
baz   one    -0.413 -0.932  1.491  0.245  0.624 -0.506
      two    -1.656 -1.053 -0.946 -0.403 -0.416  0.604
foo   one    -0.586  0.030  0.517  0.899 -0.926 -0.777
      two     1.477 -0.691 -1.330  1.022 -0.172  0.503
```

Selecting by *label*, you could do (example from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index)):

```
df.loc[:, [('bar', 'one'),]]
# try also df.loc[:, [('bar', 'two'), ('baz', 'one')]]

first           bar
second          one
first second       
bar   one    -0.771
      two    -1.777
baz   one    -0.413
      two    -1.656
foo   one    -0.586
      two     1.477
```

Now, replace with `.iloc` and keep the same exact structure:

```
df.iloc[:, [(0, 0),]]
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

The difference here was called a ["deliberate design decision"](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15228) by the pandas developers:

> `.iloc` is a strict positional indexer, it **does not** regard the structure
>   at all, only the first actual behavior. ... `.loc` **does** take into
>   account the level behavior. [emphasis added]