# python pandas multiIndex Dataframe, how to select one level based on iloc

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 2),
    columns=pd.Index(['A', 'B'], name='bar'),
    index=pd.date_range('20160101',
periods=100, freq='D', name='foo'))

corr = df.rolling(12).corr()
```

In old version, this returns a Panel, so the existing code uses

```
corr[0,:,:]
```

which returns the corr matrix of the first date.

However, in the new version, corr is a multiIndex DataFrame and the above code fails. How can I achieve the same output with minimal change?

```
corr.iloc[0] # only returns first row
corr.iloc[0,:,:] # error
```

Edit:

The desired output is to get the same return as below, but instead of using `.loc` with value, use something like `.iloc[11]` (ie the correlation matrix corresponding to the 12th value in date)

```
corr.loc['2016-01-12']

bar                    A         B
foo        bar                    
2016-01-12 A    1.000000 -0.115059
           B   -0.115059  1.000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue as alluded to by @MaxU is that `.iloc` is not "MultiIndex-aware"--see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967702/loc-and-iloc-with-multiindexd-dataframe) for a discussion.

An alternate solution for your case:

```
dates = corr.index.get_level_values(0).drop_duplicates()
corr.loc[dates[12]]  # correl. matrix for 12th date (0-indexed)
```

To retain as a DataFrame:

```
corr.loc[[dates[12]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Is that what you want?

```
In [236]: x = corr.dropna()

In [237]: x.loc[pd.IndexSlice[x.index[0][0], :], :]
Out[237]:
bar                    A         B
foo        bar
2016-01-12 A    1.000000  0.158424
           B    0.158424  1.000000
```