# Filter Multi Index dataframe by outermost index position using .iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to filter a multi index dataframe by the outermost index position using iloc[].

For the following, I can use .loc[] to accomplish this by typing out the index value.

```
              col2
Date    col1      
10/1/21 a      1.0
        b      2.0
        c      3.0
        d      4.0
        e      5.0
        f      6.0
        g      7.0
        h      8.0
        i      9.0
        j     10.0
11/1/21 k     11.0
        l     12.0
        m     13.0
        n     14.0
        o     15.0
        b     16.0
        q     17.0
        r     18.0
        s     19.0
        t     20.0
12/1/21 u     21.0
        v     22.0
        w     23.0
        x     24.0
        y     25.0
        z     26.0
```

---

This results in the desired output I'm looking for with index position.

```
df.loc['10/1/2021']



      col2
col1      
a      1.0
b      2.0
c      3.0
d      4.0
e      5.0
f      6.0
g      7.0
h      8.0
i      9.0
j     10.0
```

However, my outermost index values will change.  I would like to select all of the inner layers based on index position.  Specifically the first and last position.

.iloc[] is pulling the first result of the first layer

Ex:

```
df.iloc[0]
```

iloc[] result:

```
col2    1.0

Name: (10/1/21, a), dtype: float64
```

Is there a way for me to accomplish the desired output by index position?  Or a possible alternative to implement.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45973300/2956135

Comment: Yep, it looks like what I am trying to accomplish is either too messy or not possible