# Get index of a pandas row

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas. I have done the followings:

```
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
data.set_index(['Date','Name'],inplace=True)
```

How can I get the index (i.e., Date and Name) for a specific row (e.g., for `data.iloc[0]`)

Comment: Check `data.index[0]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`.loc\` and \`.iloc\` with MultiIndex'd DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967702/loc-and-iloc-with-multiindexd-dataframe)